# How to specify Thumbnail image size in facebook page sharing?

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing a website in PHP and I am implementing facebook sharing. I am able to select the correct image using link tag like the following (a start tag in before link)

link rel="image_src" href="http://www.code-digital.co.uk/preview.jpg" />

But Is there a way to customize the image thumbnail size? I want to show a bigger image. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using php you can select the right image with right size for you,save it to a file on your server with php, then use it as thumbnail.